# Unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 after cancelled installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I was attempting to install Ubuntu however halfway through the menus asking me to select the what types of files I would like to install I decided to cancel the installation by clicking the cancel button on the bottom of the window, I assumed I could come back to the installation at a later time however when I attempted to boot using the disk I had used flawlessly before. I was met with a message detailing that it;

`Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found`
 `Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found`
 `Failed to start MokManager: Not Found`
 `Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed`
 `: Not Found`

I attempted to wipe my computer clean so I reset the computer to factory settings five times with each attempt failing to correct the issue. I am wondering if there is a way I can fully remove the corrupted pieces and attempt a clean installation of Ubuntu from the disk since I don't have any free usb's lying around. P.S. I am attempting to set up my computer so that it can dual boot. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that in the bootable USB the file mmx64.efi didn't exist.

Solution1:

Renamed the file grubx64.efi to mmx64.efi located at folder EFI\BOOT on USB and Reboot.

Solution2:

Copy the file grubx64.efi under the name mmx64.efi (so the USB Drive folder /EFI/BOOT now contains three files: BOOTx64.EFI, grubx64.efi and mmx64.efi).
Then, reboot

Comment: The reason I am using a disk instead of a usb is because I don't have any available with sufficient space to hold the contents of the ubuntu image. Is there a way I can do this fix with a CD?

Comment: I have found an available usb and your fix has worked, thank you!

Comment: I had to rename because the partition was 'full' and file could not be copied.  Also, don't be surprised if you need to change it back again, such is the drama I had with installing.  XFS didn't seem to work for me on a dual boot Dell laptop.